# Checked box windows application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I'm working on a windows form using VB.Net in visual studio. I have added a checked box control on my user form. I am using Ms Access database and connected it with wizard.

I use the command to save the data into database as follow:

```
 Me.tblRegistrationBindingSource.EndEdit()
```

How can I save the data for the checked items in checked list box into Ms access database and how to retrieve if any modification needs to be done?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are almost there. When you call EndEdit on the binding source, that will change the RowState for the DataRow that you have modified (it will become either Added or Modified). I typically use Data Adapters with datatables.

With a data adapter, you will have four commands to wire up. SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. After wiring up the commands, you will want to call the Update method for the data adapter, passing in the datatable.

One thing that you will want to consider is the handling of primary keys. If you are working with datasets, etc, you are working with an in-memory representation of the database and not working against a live database. I use SQL server and do not know if Access will allow you to grab the primary key created by an AutoNumber field. You can try the following to your INSERT command and see if it works:`INSERT INTO TABLE (Field) VALUES(@Field)**;SELECT ID, FieldOne,... FROM Table WHERE ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()**`. If that does not work, you'll need to research that. Otherwise, you will receive an error if you try to update a record that was previously added but the primary key was not returned.

You'll also need to add the following to your project:

```
 Public Sub RowUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Data.SqlClient.SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs)
    Select Case e.StatementType
        Case StatementType.Insert
            e.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow
    End Select
End Sub
Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
AddHandler da.RowUpdated, AddressOf RowUpdated
```

Comment: I'm aware how to uodate the record. But the question is i want to update multiple value into a column. Like some have 2 hobbies, dancing and swimming. Then how can i add these two hobies into database by using checked list box control where I can check these two bobbies?

Comment: I would not recommend storing multiple values in one column. Instead, I would create a database table that is related to the parent table through a Foreign Key. Sounds like you don't need the BindingSource for what you are wanting to accomplish. Sounds like you could use the ValueChanged event and either add a DataRow or Delete a DataRow.

Comment: That's sound good. Now suppose i have created a new table with foreign key. Now how would I be able to show the hobbies in checked list box (this checked list box have multiple hobbies but only check 2 hobbies as i said above). And when i navigate next checked list box selection should changed as per the user hobbies from the database?